# If number of rows, and delete rowspan value on each click

Tags: jquery, html-table, rows

I have a `form` that creates inputs in a table row. I have now added a remove button at the end of the `tr` which removes that `tr` when clicked. I also have another function that adds to the `rowspan` of the first 3 `td`. When I remove the tr I also want to decrease the `rowspan` value of those first three `td`. Currently it only decreases that value on the first `tr` removal.

I also want to write in an if statement that will prevent the last `tr` present from being removed. Basically I always want at least one `tr` to be displayed.

The fiddle is here, http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/hmBf8/

Comment: Are you having issues with your header row or the rows that you are adding/deleting? Why would removing a TR change the rowspan? Can you strip down your jsfiddle example to just the bare essentials?

Comment: Hi Greg, the rowspan issue is not a biggie, what is very important is the user not being able to remove all the rows. I am trying to write an if statement to incorporate this. I have added a new var rowCount and I am trying to do it using that. The updated fiddle is here,http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/hmBf8/3/ Thanks

Comment: Just fixed a typo, http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/hmBf8/4/

Comment: I managed to accomplish using: if ($('.title_field').length > 1) { but as always other problems have arisen :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up checking the .length() of tds and controlling whether or not the tr could be removed or not. Then another problem arose with the first generated tr, I wanted this to never be deleted so I added a class to it and used .not() so it would not be targeted by my script.

The updated fiddle is here, http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/hmBf8/6/